# dict comprehension including list comprehension with if statement no producing the correct output

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I have some lists of text and I need to pull them together into a dictionary, but I need to use one list to 'filter' the other. I can do this in a series of nested for loops but I can not make it work with a dict comprehension.

```
a = ['Complete Yes', 'Title Mr', 'Forename John', 'Initial A', 'Surname Smith', 'Date of Birth 01 01 1901']
b = ['Forename', 'Surname', 'Date of birth']
```

If I try to make a dict of the needed details with nested `for loops` it works fine

```
details = {}
for x in b:
    for l in a:
        if x in l:
            details[x] = l

details
```

I get

```
{'Forename': 'Forename John',
 'Surname': 'Surname Smith',
 'Date of birth': 'Date of birth 01 01 1901'}
```

which needs cleaning up but I can do that later.

When I try it with a dict comprehension

```
d_tails = {x:l for x,l in zip(b, [l for l in a if x in l]) }
```

I get

```
{'Forename': 'Date of birth 01 01 1901'}
```

I'm sure this is because of how I'm ordering the dict comprehension but I can't figure out how to order it so that it replaces the for loop.

For context I'm trying to clean really messy data for terrible pdfs that where `a` comes from. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: `zip` iterates over `b` and your filtered list in parallel; your nested loop iterates over `a` completely for every item in `b`. They are two very different things, unrelated to the `dict` comprehension.

Comment: Thanks for that, I thought I had to you zip. Can you suggest how I might structure this to accomplish what I want?

Comment: By the way, you have a typo in one of your lists. `Birth` is capitalized in `a`, but not in `b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider simpler examples of two lists:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for x in a:
    for y in b:
        print(x, y)
```

This produces 9 lines of output, one for every possible combination of a value from `a` and a value from `b`.

```
for x, y in zip(a, b):
    print(x, y)
```

This produces only 3 lines of output: one for every *corresponding* pair of values taking one from `a` and one from `b`.

If you want to convert your nested loop into a single dict comprehension, you need two generators, not a single generator iterating over a `zip` object.

```
details = {x: l for x in b for l in a if x in l}
```

Comment: This is such a good answer. It not only solves the problem but clarifies what was wrong in my own learning. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1):

If I want to convert such a nested loop into a comprehension, I typically start from the outside.

You already know how the `details` dict should look in the end, so I start with that structure, and insert a placeholder `''` value:

```
details = {x: '' for x in b}
```

With list `b` out of the way, I can now only look at a given `x` (say `Forename`) and list `a`: I observe that in principle there could be *multiple* matching entries in that list, making it possible to retrieve a list of possibly matching name entries. That corresponds to a filtered list comprehension `[l for l in a if x in b]`. Combined:

```
details = {x: [l for l in a if x in b] for x in b}
```

But you wanted to have a string, and the most common case being just one match. For that, I recommend using `', '.join(...)` to convert that list of matches back to a string. At the same time, the list comprehension becomes a generator:

```
details = {x: ', '.join(l for l in a if x in b) for x in b}
```